# target indices in OpenMDAO 1.x group connections?

Tags: openmdao

By my understanding of `src_indices` in the documentation, `self.connect('a', 'b', src_indices=[1])` is roughly equivalent to `b=a[1]`.  Is there a convenient way to do "target indices" that would allow writing something like `b[1]=a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` is an output of one component, and `b` is an input of some other component, then generally a connection can only be `a->b`. So in that context `b[1] -> a` would never work, because you can't use the input as the source side of a connection.

However, if you broaden the question a little bit, and assume there are two outputs `a1` and `a2`, and you want to issue two connections as `a1 -> b[0]`, `a2 ->b[1]`, these would be "target indices." However, this isn't allowed in either OpenMDAO V1 or OpenMDAO V2. The reason is that any given input can be connected to one and only one output as its source. This restriction makes the underlying code much simpler.

In this kind of situation, you need to make a muxing component that will have two inputs and one vector output. Its `solve_nonlinear` in V1 or `compute` method in V2 will push the values into the array.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I was envisioning the second scenario you mentioned: `a1 -> b[0]`, `a2 ->b[1]`.  I have a "muxing" component as you described and will continue with that approach.